# Getting skeletal data in pykinect (xbox 360 version)

Tags: python, kinect, pykinect

I'm having trouble finding any sort of documentation or instruction for pykinect, specifically for the xbox 360 version of the kinect. how do I get skeletal data or where do I find the docs?? if I wasn't clear here please let me know!

Comment: Do [their examples](https://github.com/Kinect/PyKinect2/blob/master/examples/PyKinectBodyGame.py) not help? Does anything in that source code not make sense to you?

Comment: this is pykinect2 it does not work with the xbox 360 version which uses the version 1.8 sdk

Comment: How about the pykinect example? https://github.com/abhirajD/PyKinect/blob/master/examples/PyKinectBodyGame.py

Comment: once again this also uses the pykinect2 package, it should just say import pykinect I believe

Comment: Okay I'll just show myself out

Comment: I'm sorry if that seemed rude that was not at all the intention, are these compatible, i'm quite new to this.

Comment: I have no idea, I guess not, I just was not being helpful so that's why I was saying I was leaving, so I don't waste your time

Comment: well thank you for trying!!

Answer (score -2):

To use python with the kinect 360 you need the follwing:

python 2.7
windows kinect sdk 1.8
pykinect   - NOT pykinect2